# How to check if an excel cell is empty using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am taking input from an excel sheet using Poi.jar and wanted to know how to check if a cell is empty or not.

Right now I m using the below code.

```
cell = myRow.getCell(3);
if (cell != null) {
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

    //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
    if (cell.getStringCellValue() != "")
        depend[p] = Integer.parseInt(cell.getStringCellValue());

    }
}
```

Comment: `if(cell.getStringCellValue() != "")` is wrong. It should be `if(!cell.getStringCellValue().equals(""))`.

Answer (score 80):

If you're using Apache POI 4.x, you can do that with:

```
 Cell c = row.getCell(3);
 if (c == null || c.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK) {
    // This cell is empty
 }
```

For older Apache POI 3.x versions, which predate the move to the `CellType` enum, it's:

```
 Cell c = row.getCell(3);
 if (c == null || c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
    // This cell is empty
 }
```

Don't forget to check if the `Row` is null though - if the row has never been used with no cells ever used or styled, the row itself might be null!

Comment: this is giving me NPE in some of the cases

Comment: You need to ensure that the row isn't null - the code here will work fine for a non-null row as it already contains a cell null check!

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr. That explains. But how do i check if the row is null in an if/while condition? I couldn't find a function for that.

Comment: Umm, what about `if (row == null) { // Do something for an empty row }` ?

Comment: Your code won't work if someone assumes that an excel cell is also empty if it contains an empty string (""). See my answer for the additional code check.

Comment: @winklerrr Excel should write an empty string as a blank cell, so that shouldn't happen

Comment: @Gagravarr It's true that Excel does this. But it doesn't work if the content of a cell is changed and then checked for emptiness in the same Java program. If you want to, I can provide a unit test to make my case more clear.

Comment: c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK now depricated

Comment: @irJvV You just need to wait for Apache POI 4.0, then it won't be, it's part of the shuffle from int to enum!

Comment: It would be great if all participants in stackoverflow would understand how important package names are.

Comment: c.getCellType() gives me a null pointer exception because the cell is null.  using poi version >5

Comment: @AnjanBiswas You still need the `null` check first, to guard against the cell having nothing in it and so not existing in the file

Answer (score 34):

Gagravarr's answer is quite good!

---

## Check if an excel cell is empty

But if you assume that a **cell is also empty if it contains an empty String** (`""`), you need some additional code. This can happen, if a cell was edited and then not cleared properly (for how to clear a cell properly, see further below).

I wrote myself a helper to check if an `XSSFCell` is empty (including an empty String).

```
 /**
 * Checks if the value of a given {@link XSSFCell} is empty.
 * 
 * @param cell
 *            The {@link XSSFCell}.
 * @return {@code true} if the {@link XSSFCell} is empty. {@code false}
 *         otherwise.
 */
public static boolean isCellEmpty(final XSSFCell cell) {
    if (cell == null) { // use row.getCell(x, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK) to avoid null cells
        return true;
    }

    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
        return true;
    }

    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING && cell.getStringCellValue().trim().isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Pay attention for newer POI Version**

They first changed `getCellType()` to `getCellTypeEnum()` as of Version `3.15 Beta 3` and then moved back to `getCellType()` as of Version `4.0`.

- Version `>= 3.15 Beta 3`:

  - Use `CellType.BLANK` and `CellType.STRING` instead of `Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK` and `Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING`
- Version `>= 3.15 Beta 3` &&  Version `< 4.0`

  - Use `Cell.getCellTypeEnum()` instead of `Cell.getCellType()`

But better [double check yourself](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/), because they planned to change it back in future releases.

---

### Example

This JUnit test shows the case in which the additional empty check is needed.

Scenario: the content of a cell is changed within a Java program. Later on, in the same Java program, the cell is checked for emptiness. The test will fail if the `isCellEmpty(XSSFCell cell)` function doesn't check for empty Strings.

```
@Test
public void testIsCellEmpty_CellHasEmptyString_ReturnTrue() {
    // Arrange
    XSSFCell cell = new XSSFWorkbook().createSheet().createRow(0).createCell(0);

    boolean expectedValue = true;
    boolean actualValue;

    // Act
    cell.setCellValue("foo");
    cell.setCellValue("bar");
    cell.setCellValue(" ");
    actualValue = isCellEmpty(cell);

    // Assert
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
}
```

---

### In addition: Clear a cell properly

Just in case if someone wants to know, how to clear the content of a cell properly. There are two ways to archive that (I would recommend *way 1*).

```
// way 1
public static void clearCell(final XSSFCell cell) {
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
}

// way 2
public static void clearCell(final XSSFCell cell) {
    String nullString = null;
    cell.setCellValue(nullString); 
}
```

Why way 1? **Explicit is better than implicit** (thanks, Python)

Way 1: sets the cell type **explicitly** back to `blank`.
Way 2: sets the cell type **implicitly** back to `blank` due to a side effect when setting a cell value to a `null` String.

---

#### Useful sources

- [Official Documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/)

  - [CellTypes](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html)
  - [XSSFCell.setCellValue(String)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#setCellValue-java.lang.String-)
  - [Cell.setCellType(CellType)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType-)

Regards winklerrr

Comment: How is it with numbers? Can cell be of type NUMERIC and still be empty?

Comment: @JanZyka No, a numeric cell would have at least a value of `0`. So you could see that value in the sheet. A numeric cell can't be "empty" in that way because you can't set the cell's value to a `null` double value. The setter for double values only accepts the primitive double type as you can see [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#setCellValue-double-). In contrast to that, the setter for the string value also accepts `null` values which will lead to an automatic conversion of the cell's type to `CellType.BLANK`.

Comment: @Sandro thanks for your comment about the `trim()` method. Forgot this case. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I've just deleted my answer as it doesn't seem to be possible to format multi line code snippets well. I've created an answer instead.

Answer (score 6):

As of Apache POI 3.17 you will have to check if the cell is empty using enumerations:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;

if(cell == null || cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BLANK) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(x, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
```

This trick helped me a lot, see if it's useful for you

Answer (score 2):

First to avoid NullPointerException you have to add this

```
Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK
```

This will create a blank cell instead of giving you NPE then you can check to make sure nothing went wrong just like what @Gagravarr have said.

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(j, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
    if (cell == null || cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BLANK) 
        // do what you want
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the safest and most concise way I see as of POI 3.1.7 up to POI 4:

```
boolean isBlankCell = CellType.BLANK == cell.getCellTypeEnum();
boolean isEmptyStringCell = CellType.STRING == cell.getCellTypeEnum() && cell.getStringCellValue().trim().isEmpty(); 

if (isBlankCell || isEmptyStringCell) {
    ...
```

As of POI 4 `getCellTypeEnum()` will be deprecated if favor of `getCellType()` but the return type should stay the same.

Comment: Pay attention: the deprecated that method in POI Apache 3.15, but as of Version 4 it's called `getCellType()` again.

Answer (score 1):

**Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK** is work in my case.

```
total_colume = myRow.getLastCellNum();
int current_colume = 0;
HSSFCell ReadInCellValue;

while (current_colume <= total_colume) {
   ReadInCellValue = myRow.getCell(current_colume, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);//if cell is empty, return black
   if (ReadInCellValue.toString=="") Log.d("empty cell", "colume=" + String.valuOf(current_colume));
   current_colume++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one other option also .

```
row=(Row) sheet.getRow(i);
        if (row == null || isEmptyRow(row)) {
            return;
        }
Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
    while (cells.hasNext())
     {}
```

Comment: Where is the check if the currently iterated cell is empty or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK
```

Comment: Please note that code only answers are discouraged!

Answer (score 0):

`Cell.getCellType()` is deprecated in the latest POI API. If you are using POI API version 3.17, use the below code:

```
if (Cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BLANK) {
    //do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Pay attention: they deprecated that method in POI Apache 3.15, but as of Version 4 it's called `getCellType()` again.

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use switch case like**

```
                    String columndata2 = "";
                    if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 1) {// To match column index

                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                                columndata2 = "";
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                columndata2 = "" + cell.getNumericCellValue();
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                columndata2 = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("Cell Value "+ columndata2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
String empty = "-";
if (row.getCell(3) == null || row.getCell(3).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
    upld.setValue(empty);
} else {
    upld.setValue(row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
}
```